# How to change color of svg image in android. Images are downloaded from web api

Tags: java, android, svg

I have an issue something like, I am downloading a image from web api and successfully set into imageview. I am unable to change the color of svg image that I downloaded.
I tried tintColor in xml and setFilterColor() from .java file but nothing is work for me.
Is there any solution please reply on this post.

```
public static void loadSvgWithColor(final Context context, String url, final int color, final ImageView target) {
    if (httpClient == null) {
        httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cache(new Cache(context.getCacheDir(), 5 * 1024 * 1014))
                .build();
    }
    if (!url.equals("")) {
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
        httpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                target.setImageResource(R.drawable.app_icon);
                target.setColorFilter(color);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                InputStream stream = response.body().byteStream();
                Sharp.loadInputStream(stream).into(target);
                stream.close();
                target.setColorFilter(color);
       }
        });
    } else {
        target.setImageResource(R.drawable.app_icon);
        target.setColorFilter(color);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit the stream of svg file when you received of api, and set into imageview 
By this sample:
[image: without Edit color]

[image: Edited color]

Comment: Thank you, it is what I have ended up doing today.

Answer (score 0):

The Sharp library you are using generates a `PictureDrawable` and puts that in your `ImageView`.  Last I checked, the `android:tint` and `setColorFilter()` methods don't work on PictureDrawables.

I can think of a couple of solutions:

- Use Sharp's festure to change the colour when rendering. See their demo at: https://github.com/Pixplicity/sharp/blob/master/sample-imageview/src/main/java/com/pixplicity/sharp/imageviewdemo/SvgDemoActivity.java
- Use a different library, such as my [AndroidSVG](https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvg), which let's you style the SVG with CSS when rendering.